# What is the implementation of Docker on Ubuntu Core in terms of Snap sandbox instance

Tags: snap, docker, ubuntu-core, container

I installed the Docker Snap on Ubuntu Core using the following commands:

```
sudo snap install docker
```

I have been able to create create a **Dockerfile** and a **docker-compose.yaml** file to build a image using `docker compose build`.  I can also run the image I built as a docker container.  Everything seems to work similar to Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server.

I want to know a little bit of the details on the implementation of Docker on Ubuntu Core.  The Docker Snap is in it's own sandbox.  Here is the questions I have:

- When I use `docker run` to instantiate and run the images do they all live in the one Docker Snap sandbox or is there now multiple Docker Snap sandboxes created for each Docker container instantiated?
- What command(s) can I run to see what Snap the docker container is running in?
- What command(s) can I run to see any process running on Ubuntu Core and which Snap sandbox it is running in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that they all live in one snap sandbox. Snap doesn't sandbox separately per instance of the same application. So all the docker instances you run are under the one security context. That makes the second and third question moot.